# Parse error using multiple `or` conditions

Tags: php, or-condition

I am having issues using multiple `or` conditions.

Here the code, very simple :

```
<?php

$a = "a";

if($a == "a" || $a == "b" || $a == "c" || $a == "d" || $a == "e")
{echo "test";}

?>
```

But PHP displays this error :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$a' (T_VARIABLE) in
>   /home/guest/public_html/or.php on line 5

Comment: Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Works fine [here](https://eval.in/429557). Check the source for invisible characters.

Comment: Either you don't show us your real code. Or you have some weird characters or something in your code

Comment: No no, it's the right code !

Comment: You can download the file and try it http://www.filedropper.com/or

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was right in the comments: it's a (yet another) Case of Invisible Characters. Here's what's really stored in your file:

```
if($a == "a" ||\u00A0$a == "b" ||\u00A0$a == "c" || $a == "d" || $a == "e")
```

As you see, in two places `$a` is preceded not with a normal whitespace, but with something else - a special character, so called [Non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) one. It's not visually different from a normal whitespace, and it's truncated by StackOverflow engine when you paste the code into the question. But it messes up how the parser interprets your code - hence an error.

Comment: I use text editor called geany in debian distro

Comment: It's easy to check - just remove all the whitespace after `||` operands (PHP allows it). Then I'd suggest runing `find-and-replace` to replace all non-breaking space with a normal space.

Comment: You're right because the code works with vi editor

Comment: Thank you very much, solved !

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is an excerpt of your code, and the `line 5` is (most probably) the line with `$a="a";`. Check for an incomplete `{}` or a missing `;` prior to that line.

Comment: No line 5 matches if($a == "a" || $a == "b" ...)

you can download and try it : filedropper.com/or